# How to extract part of SQL query from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to to extract SQL queries that are saved in a table? 
For example

`select * from  saved_queries`

```
name      | statement    
queryname | 'select * from mytable where myfield = 'somevalue'
```

I would like to be able to do something like

`select * from ( extractsomehow( 'select Statement from saved_queries where  name = 'queryname') )`.

Unfortunately I cannot use Java so I am restricted to SQL and XML there.

I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: To say that it is not possible would probably be wrong, but this is VERY poor practice.

Comment: Using stored procedures does effectively the same thing, is faster, safer,easier and in Oracle you can even package related stored procedures together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write a stored procedure, you could use [`execute immediate`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm), something like this:

```
select statement into v_statement from saved_queries where ... ;
execute immediate v_statement;
```

Before you use [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm), think carefully about whether or not you actually need it.